# Action as generic type in constructor gives compile error

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

Why does the constructor overload in `Funky<T>` have an issue with the *action* parameter but the subclass `FunkyAction` does not?

```
class Funky<T>
{
    readonly T _data;

    public Funky(T data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public Funky(Action action, bool imJustAnOverload)
        : this(action) // cannot convert from 'System.Action' to 'T'
    {
    }
}   


class FunkyAction : Funky<Action>
{
    public FunkyAction(Action action)
        : base(action) // no compile error
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `action` != `T` in your base class. `T` could be anything. In your derived class `T` is an `Action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructor:

```
public Funky(Action action, bool imJustAnOverload)
    : this(action)
```

is trying to use this constructor:

```
public Funky(T data)
```

passing an `Action` as a argument to a parameter of type `T`.

Since `T` is a generic type paremeter, then the compiler cannot guarantee that `action` can be casted to `T`. As far as the compiler is concerned, `T` could be an `int` or a `string`.

Now, for the derived class, this constructor:

```
public FunkyAction(Action action)
    : base(action)
```

Is trying to use this base class constructor:

```
 public Funky(T action)
```

But since it is defining `T` as `Action` (in `class FunkyAction : Funky<Action>`), then the base constructor actually looks like this (from the perspective of `FunkyAction` in specific):

```
public Funky(Action action)
```

Now there is no problem passing an argument of type `Action` to a method that expects an `Action`.

You could make the base class constructor generic like this:

```
public Funky(T action, bool imJustAnOverload)
        : this(action)
    {
    }
```

That will allow you to create a `Funky<Action>` and construct it with an `Action` like this:

```
Funky<Action> funky = new Funky<Action>(() => DoSomething(), true);
```

Comment: Ok, yes - the _constraints_ explanation is useful. I used to work with C++ (years ago!) and I think I was, for a moment, confusing the two languages.

Comment: @mungflesh, please note that you cannot specify a constraint for `T` to be an `Action`. I modified the answer.